# Constructing tangent to a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, tangent-line

I've been studying Basic Mathematics for Physics courses.

While teaching about derivatives my prof. said that there are actually two points the tangent at a point passes through (and those points are almost coincident). Symbolically $x_0$ and $x_0+\mathrm dx$. Clearly this sounds absurd because a tangent by definition touches any curve only at a single point. But also, this puts forth the discrepancy that at least two points are required to construct a line.

I thought that if we somehow know the curvature of the curve we would indeed be able to construct a tangent using only a single point by using definition of curvature, $\kappa=1/r$ and follow as we do in the case of a circle.

But how to actually measure the curvature of curve using only its derivative? Feel free to present a model of constructing a tangent this way or any other that you may find relevant and fitting into intermediate-to-advanced calculus courses.

Comment: While a tangent line MAY intersect a curve many times ($y=1$ on $f(x)=\sin x$ for example) it's not mandatory and it's certainly not because $x+dx$ is an actual number different from $x$.

Comment: And before a bunch of non-standard analysts chime in: yeah, I know.

Comment: @Randall I do know that the tangent may intersect the curve more than once. I meant the point of tangency is the only point at which the tangent touches the curve at that $x$-value.

Comment: Yes, hence the second part of my comment.

Comment: You cannot construct tangents of arbitrary curves, just as you cannot compute limits of arbitrary functions. You can approximate them.

Comment: @Randall I get the first part. Could you also provide insight for the geometrical construction of the tangent using entities as curvature and radius?

Comment: @user647486 Thanks for pointing that out, I've changed the title from "any" to "a" curve to which the tangent is constructible. That would simply require existence of the derivative or simply the function being differentiable at that point. Right?

Comment: I cannot, but I think it's a good question.  Curvature formulas typically contain the second derivative somewhere, so it's not far-fetched to think the derivative could inform this (and hence the tangent line).  @ParasKhosla

Comment: Don't refer to your "previous question". Don't assume that we are aware.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sure I would keep that in mind. :)

Comment: @ParasKhosla But I don't mean only existence of the derivative, I mean also being able to construct it.

Comment: @user647486 Could you be more precise in what you mean?. I mean the ability of constructing the tangent somehow has to depend on the existence of _some_-order derivative of that curve at that point.

Comment: Thanks for discussing and working through my question. @Randall

Comment: The tangent is, by definition a line passing through the point of the curve and having slope equal to the limit of the slopes of chords having an end-point at that point. Given the curve and the point, constructing the tangent is the same as being able to construct its slope, and therefore compute that limit. For example, if the curve is a circle then you can construct the slope of the tangent by taking advantage of the symmetry of the circle. In every case it is going to depend on specific properties of the curve, if possible at all.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @user647486 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is wrong. Knowing the curvature does not help you to construct the tangent. Just think that circles of any radius can be tangent to a given straight line.

And computing the curvature requires both the first and second derivative.

---

The intuition behind the two-points construction is that the chord by the target point and an extra point will tend to the tangent when the two points get closer.

[image]

Comment: Ah, correct.  The curvature will not inform the "tilt."

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Yves Daoust

Answer (score 0):

Consider the differential quotient
$$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}.$$
Here $f'(x_0)$ is the slope of the tangent line to $f$ at $x_0$ with $x_0$ given.

For this quotient, the tangent line is $f(x)-f(x_0) = f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ or better $f(x) = f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my question is more about using geometric methods and entities such as curvature and radius and following with how we construct tangents to circles.

Comment: I think OP knows this.  This isn't really the question.